# AWS jar file: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, executable-jar

I deployed the jar file in the AWS instance and trying to run the application like

> java -cp .;./sample.jar com.sample.mani.core.FRS

I'm getting the error

> -bash: ./sample.jar: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

the same thing is working in the local but not working in the AWS instance can any one help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to execute `.jar` file using `bash` (./sample.jar).

You have to run something like : `java -jar sample.jar`.